# I can't understand why I can't take the records by index in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe, when I use index to show the record it's work.

```
In [84]: Print(file152['Dept Code'][8030])
Out[85]:'DSEC4K'

In [85]: file152['Dept Code'][8037]
Out[85]: 'BTAWTC'
```

but when I use a range, it doesn't work.

```
In [86]: file152['Dept Code'][8030:8037]
Out[86]: Series([], Name: Dept Code, dtype: object)

In [87]  file152['Dept Code'].iloc[8030:8037]
Out[87]: Series([], Name: Dept Code, dtype: object)
```

Comment: if there has sample will be better.in pandas you can indexing data like this `file152[8030:8037,'Dept Code']`

Comment: I tested what you're doing in pandas 1.3.1 and both of the "range" options worked. However, you should really use loc and iloc correctly `file152.loc[8030:8037, 'Dept Code']`